# Hello, I encountered a problem in django. Here is the error that I got

Tags: django

The Error:

> ValueError at /admin/saling_stuff_site/menproduct/add/
>
> Invalid format string
>
> Request Method:   POST Request URL:
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/saling_stuff_site/menproduct/add/ Django
> Version:  3.2 Exception Type:     ValueError Exception Value:
>
> Invalid format string
>
> Exception Location:   D:\django sale site\sale
> site\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py, line
> 318, in generate_filename Python Executable:  D:\django sale site\sale
> site\venv\Scripts\python.exe Python Version:  3.8.5 Python Path:
>
> ['D:\django sale site\sale site\vending_site',  'C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Python38-32\python38.zip',  'C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Python38-32\DLLs',  'C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Python38-32\lib',  'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32',
> 'D:\django sale site\sale site\venv',  'D:\django sale site\sale
> site\venv\lib\site-packages']

Here is models.py

```
> from django.db import models
> 
> class MenCategory(models.Model):
>     title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
>     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Url', unique=True)
> 
>     def __str__(self):
>         return self.title
> 
>     class Meta:
>         ordering = ['title']
> 
> class WomenCategory(models.Model):
>     title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
>     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Url', unique=True)
> 
>     def __str__(self):
>         return self.title
> 
>     class Meta:
>         ordering = ['title']
> 
> 
> class SubCategoryMen(models.Model):
>     title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
>     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Url', unique=True)
>     category = models.ManyToManyField(MenCategory, blank=True, related_name='product')
> 
>     def __str__(self):
>         return self.title
> 
>     class Meta:
>         ordering = ['title']
> 
> 
> class SubCategoryWomen(models.Model):
>     title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
>     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Url', unique=True)
>     category = models.ManyToManyField(WomenCategory, blank=True, related_name='product')
> 
>     def __str__(self):
>         return self.title
> 
>     class Meta:
>         ordering = ['title']
> 
> 
> class MenProduct(models.Model):
>     title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
>     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Url', unique=True)
>     content = models.TextField(blank=True)
>     posted_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Опубликовано')
>     photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%')
>     category = models.ForeignKey(MenCategory, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='MenProduct')
>     subcategory = models.ManyToManyField(SubCategoryMen, blank=True, related_name='MenProduct')
> 
> 
>     class Meta:
>         ordering = ['-posted_at']
> 
> 
> class WomenProduct(models.Model):
>     title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
>     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Url', unique=True)
>     content = models.TextField(blank=True)
>     posted_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Опубликовано')
>     photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%')
>     category = models.ForeignKey(WomenCategory, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='WomenProduct')
>     subcategory = models.ManyToManyField(SubCategoryWomen, blank=True, related_name='WomenProduct')
> 
> 
>     class Meta:
>         ordering = ['-posted_at']
```

here is admin.py

```
> from django.contrib import admin from django import forms from .models
> import * from ckeditor_uploader.widgets import CKEditorUploadingWidget
> 
> 
> class MenProductAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
>     content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorUploadingWidget())
> 
>     class Meta:
>         model = MenProduct
>         fields = '__all__'
> 
> 
> class MenProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
>     prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ('title',)}
>     form = MenProductAdminForm
> 
> 
> class WomenProductAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
>     content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorUploadingWidget())
> 
>     class Meta:
>         model = WomenProduct
>         fields = '__all__'
> 
> 
> class WomenProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
>     prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ('title',)}
>     form = WomenProductAdminForm
> 
> 
> class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
>     prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ('title',)}
> 
> 
> class SubCategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
>     prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ('title',)}
> 
> 
> admin.site.register(MenCategory, CategoryAdmin)
> admin.site.register(SubCategoryMen, SubCategoryAdmin)
> admin.site.register(WomenCategory, CategoryAdmin)
> admin.site.register(SubCategoryWomen, SubCategoryAdmin)
> admin.site.register(MenProduct, MenProductAdmin)
> admin.site.register(WomenProduct, WomenProductAdmin)
```

here is settings.py

```
> from pathlib import Path import os
> # Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'. BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
> 
> 
> # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
> # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/
> 
> # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret! SECRET_KEY =
> 'django-insecure-i2nqg9x!^y-&%cdedc#=l6@!(j5h*e(@d2^q5qwi11edr4(s@h'
> 
> # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production! DEBUG = True
> 
> ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
> 
> 
> # Application definition
> 
> INSTALLED_APPS = [
>     'django.contrib.admin',
>     'django.contrib.auth',
>     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
>     'django.contrib.sessions',
>     'django.contrib.messages',
>     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
>     'debug_toolbar',
>     'ckeditor',
>     'saling_stuff_site.apps.SalingStuffSiteConfig', ]
> 
> MIDDLEWARE = [
>     'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
>     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
>     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
>     'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
>     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', ]
> 
> ROOT_URLCONF = 'vending_site.urls'
> 
> TEMPLATES = [
>     {
>         'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
>         'DIRS': [
>             os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
>         ],
>         'APP_DIRS': True,
>         'OPTIONS': {
>             'context_processors': [
>                 'django.template.context_processors.debug',
>                 'django.template.context_processors.request',
>                 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
>                 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
>             ],
>         },
>     }, ]
> 
> WSGI_APPLICATION = 'vending_site.wsgi.application'
> 
> 
> 
> 
> DATABASES = {
>     'default': {
>         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
>         'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
>     } }
> 
> 
> 
> 
> AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
>     {
>         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
>     },
>     {
>         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
>     },
>     {
>         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
>     },
>     {
>         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
>     }, ]
> 
> 
> 
> 
> LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
> 
> TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
> 
> USE_I18N = True
> 
> USE_L10N = True
> 
> USE_TZ = True
> 
> 
> 
> 
> STATIC_URL = '/static/' STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
> STATICFILES_DIRS = [
>     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'vending_site/static'), ]
> 
> MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
> 
> INTERNAL_IPS = [ '127.0.0.1' ]
> 
> CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
> 
> 
> 
> 
> CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
>     'default': {
>         'skin': 'moono',
>         # 'skin': 'office2013',
>         'toolbar_Basic': [
>             ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
>         ],
>         'toolbar_YourCustomToolbarConfig': [
>             {'name': 'document', 'items': ['Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates']},
>             {'name': 'clipboard', 'items': ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']},
>             {'name': 'editing', 'items': ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll']},
>             {'name': 'forms',
>              'items': ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton',
>                        'HiddenField']},
>             '/',
>             {'name': 'basicstyles',
>              'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat']},
>             {'name': 'paragraph',
>              'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-',
>                        'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl',
>                        'Language']},
>             {'name': 'links', 'items': ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']},
>             {'name': 'insert',
>              'items': ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe']},
>             '/',
>             {'name': 'styles', 'items': ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']},
>             {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
>             {'name': 'tools', 'items': ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks']},
>             {'name': 'about', 'items': ['About']},
>             '/',  # put this to force next toolbar on new line
>             {'name': 'yourcustomtools', 'items': [
>                 # put the name of your editor.ui.addButton here
>                 'Preview',
>                 'Maximize',
> 
>             ]},
>         ],
>         'toolbar': 'YourCustomToolbarConfig',  # put selected toolbar config here
>         # 'toolbarGroups': [{ 'name': 'document', 'groups': [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] }],
>         # 'height': 291,
>         # 'width': '100%',
>         # 'filebrowserWindowHeight': 725,
>         # 'filebrowserWindowWidth': 940,
>         # 'toolbarCanCollapse': True,
>         # 'mathJaxLib': '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.2-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
>         'tabSpaces': 4,
>         'extraPlugins': ','.join([
>             'uploadimage', # the upload image feature
>             # your extra plugins here
>             'div',
>             'autolink',
>             'autoembed',
>             'embedsemantic',
>             'autogrow',
>             # 'devtools',
>             'widget',
>             'lineutils',
>             'clipboard',
>             'dialog',
>             'dialogui',
>             'elementspath'
>         ]),
>     } }
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

here is urls.py

```
> from django.contrib import admin from django.urls import path, include
> from django.conf import settings from django.conf.urls.static import
> static
> 
> urlpatterns = [
>     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
>     path('', include('saling_stuff_site.urls')),
>     path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')), ]
> 
> if settings.DEBUG:
>     import debug_toolbar
> 
>     urlpatterns = [
>         path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
>     ] + urlpatterns
> 
>     urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and here is the second url.py

```
> from django.urls import path from .views import *
> 
> urlpatterns = [
>     path('', index, name='home'), ]
```

Comment: Your `upload_to` kwarg for `ImageField`: `upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%')` seems to be missing something, perhaps you meant to write `upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')`?

Comment: oh yes i meant that but i added to MenProduct and WomenProduct      price = models.IntegerField()  and now i have an OperationalError at /admin/saling_stuff_site/womenproduct/add/ table saling_stuff_site_womenproduct has no column named price

Comment: You need to _migrate_ after changing the models... Run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`...

Comment: when i do python manage.py migrate i have an other error like this: django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "saling_stuff_site_menproduct" already exists